# Infinite intersections of open sets become closed? (Alexandrov topology)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

There is a [one-to-one mapping between pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) and Alexandrov topology. The topology, or open sets, are defined to be the upper set of pre-order $\succsim$. Also note that the definition for Alexandrov topology is that arbitrary intersection of open sets is open.

However, I have a "counterexample":

Consider $[0,1]$. Let the pre-order be the usual order on reals. A sequence of upper-set is therefore $(1/n,1]$. The intersection of this sequence converges to $\{1\}$, which is not an upper set, and therefore not an open set. This implies that the induced topology of usual order is not Alexandrov.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Why do you think $\{1\}$ is not an upper set?  It has the necessary property (if $a \in \{1\}$ and $b \in [0, 1]$ is such that $a \leq b$ then $b \in \{1\}$).

Comment: Oh so $\{1\}$ is a closed set by conventional wisdom but open in this Alex topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The intersection of this sequence converges to $\{1\}$, which is not an upper set

It is. A subset consisting of maximal elements only is always an upper set. And therefore it is open in the Alexandrov topology.

In particular this topology does not coincide with the Euclidean one, even though they both arise from ordering (in a different way though).